# MongDB cannot find Promise type definition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, promise

I have created a new project, installed few type definitions (from DefinitelyTyped) and made a basic `src/go.ts` file.

Whenever I transpile the code, I get a ton of `TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'` errors!
The `./typings/mongodb/index.d.ts` is referencing the `Promise`, but the compiler does not seem to find that.
**Please note that I have `dt~promise` installed as well.**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQhDX.png)  *(Errors on the left side, type definitions installed and the app code are on the right)*

Content of `typings.json`:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "registry:dt/dotenv#2.0.0+20160327131627",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160805091045",
    "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "mongodb": "registry:dt/mongodb#2.1.0+20160602142941",
    "mongoose": "registry:dt/mongoose#4.5.4+20160807120805",
    "mongoose-promise": "registry:dt/mongoose-promise#4.5.4+20160720003345",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350",
    "promise": "registry:dt/promise#7.1.1+20160602154553",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160606155157"
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced the same issue (more or less, using @types instead of typings) and was able to solve it by installing the type definitions for **[CoreJS](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)**.

#### [Screenshots](http://postimg.org/gallery/1qb1ace2k/)

Apologize for linking to a library, this is my first post so I am unable to provide more than two links per post.

#### Image explanations:

- First screenshot shows similar error, type definition file for MongoDB is unable to find 'Promise'.
- Install type definitions for CoreJS. Note that I am getting my type definitions through NPM and not Typings. So to do something similar in Typings you would run something like:

  - `typings install dt~core-js --save --global`
- Third screenshot shows build command with no errors on output

I hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue installing lastest version of mongodb and mongoose typings.

The new definition file for mongodb assumes you are using ES6 promise so if you change the `target` of the typescript compiler in the `tsconfig.json` to `es6` it should do the trick :

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "target": "ES6",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting same issue as explained above and got resolved by this solution, Thanks!

Comment: in most cases, you REALLY DONT WANT ES6 as your compilation target.  This will cause massive usability issues on any client-side code, among other issues.  Please re-think this.

Comment: We are talking about **Server side JavaScript** so here this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For typings: `typings install core-js --ambient --save`.
It works for me.